# Add category only if post has custom taxonomy category

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, save-post

I'm trying to add a category to a post that has a custom tax category applied. If the post has the custom tax category, it should also get a standard category.

So the code below will add the standard category, but it adds it to every post that is saved, not just the ones with the custom tax category. What am I doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_new_category' );

function set_new_category( $post_id ) {
//Define new category by ID
$new_category = 27;

//Define the custom taxonomy
$em_taxonomy = 'event-category';

// Get the custom taxonomy category by slug
$old_term = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'building-reservations', $em_taxonomy );

// Check if post has custom taxonomy category applied
if (!$old_term)

    //If not, don't do anything
    return; 

    //Append with the new category
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $new_category, $append = true ); 
}
```

Comment: Try this: `// Check if post has custom taxonomy category applied
if ($old_term)
 //Append with the new category
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $new_category, $append = true ); 
}`

Comment: That new code didn't change anything. It still applies the new category to any post regardless of the already set custom tax category.

Comment: Forgot to include the new code for reference: `add_action( 'save_post', 'set_new_category' );
function set_new_category( $post_id ) {
    //Define new category by ID
    $new_category = 27;
    //Define the custom taxonomy
    $em_taxonomy = 'event-category';
    // Get the custom taxonomy category by slug
    $old_term = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'building-reservations', $em_taxonomy );
    // Check if post has custom taxonomy category applied
    if ($old_term)
        //Append with the new category
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $new_category, $append = true ); 
}`

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args )` expects third param to be an array of arguments.

> Params
>
> $post_id (integer) (optional) The Post ID Default: 0
>
> $taxonomy
>   (string|array) (optional) The taxonomy for which to retrieve terms.
>   Defaults to post_tag. Default: 'post_tag'
>
> $args (array) (optional)
>   Overwrite the defaults Default: array

My guess is that `$old_term` is being set to `wp_get_post_terms` response of a WP_Error. So it is always true when you're checking it.

> Response
>
> (array|WP_Error)  An array of taxonomy terms, or empty array if no
>   terms are found. WP_Error if $taxonomy does not exist. See
>   is_wp_error() for more information.

You can verify the response is good with something like:

```
if( is_array( $old_term ) && ! empty( $old_term ) ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

---

If you are trying be sure that the post has the taxonomy term `building_reservations` from the taxonomy of `event_category`, perhaps something close to this will work:

```
$old_term = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $em_taxonomy );

if( is_array( $old_term ) && ! empty( $old_term ) ) {

    if ( in_array( 'building_reservations', $old_term ) {

        wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $new_category, $append = true ); 
    }
}
```